# ODP.NET x64 ANYCPU and Prefer 32-bit setting

Tags: odp.net, anycpu

My machine has the latest Oracle ODP.NET x64 installed (xCopy version). My machine is x64. I don't know if the target machines will be x86 or x64 so I have set the build properties to AnyCPU in VS 2012. There is a default checkbox active "prefer 32-bit"

Compilation is OK but when I run the code it says it can't find the assembly. Unchecking "prefer 32-bit" solves this problem.

But what is causing this? I would assume that prefering 32-bits is okay but that it would use x64 if that's the only option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

"Any CPU" with "Prefer 32-bit" will run as a 32-bit process on 64-bit machines. And because a 32-bit process can't load the 64-bit ODP.NET assemblies (and native DLLs too), it throws the exception you mentioned.

You can read more about the "Prefer 32-bit" setting here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12066861/631802