# Application not launching on x86 build but launching on 64-bit

Tags: c#, x86-64, projects-and-solutions

I have created a WPF Windows Application project based on the existing standards in the solution. The project properties had `Platform Target` as `Any CPU` and says `Prefer 32-bit`. Mine is a 64-bit machine and the application wasn't launching, it took me while to figure out and turned off `Prefer 32-bit` to launch it.

My question is what is happening when I say `Prefer 32-bit`? I expect it to launch it as a 32 bit application on a 64-bit machine. But in my case it does not run, it simply terminates. Why?

**Edit:**

The problem was when I say `Prefer 32-bit` or `x86` it builds the application in 32-bit mode. `Any CPU` makes it a 64-bit build. The application launches only in 64-bit mode and when launched with `32-bit` mode it terminates without any exception.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066638/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-prefer-32-bit-setting-in-visual-studio-2012-and-how

Comment: Can you explain in more details the phrase `and the application wasn't launching`.

Comment: @yakiro Thanks for the reference to the link, Based on the explanation I expect the application to launch even on a 64-bit machine as a 32 bit application. The link doesn't explain on why it will not launch.

Comment: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-4-5-and-visual-studio-11.aspx

Comment: @Bharath so what you're asking is why you application crashed right? have you checked the Application log (in the event viewer) for some hints?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @yakiro it didnt give me much info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trial and error found out that problem is with the length of the `AssemblyName`. It was 56 character long after I reduced it to say 36 character it worked fine. Could not get information on whats the permissible limit for 32-bit assembly name and 64-bit assembly name. But 64 bit allows bigger names which has caused the confusion.