# OutOfMemoryException with gcAllowVeryLargeObjects

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory, .net-4.5, gcallowverylargeobjects

I'm using a BinarySerializer with a pretty big (althought not very deep) graph of items. I have 8GB of ram backed by 12Gig of swap and i'm getting an OutOfMemoryException when serializing which is expected ( it's possible the graph could go near or over 2Gb).

However when i use gcAllowVeryLargeObjects it's no better, i still get the same exception and i'm definately working on something that should hold in memory (at least with the swap).

Is there anything i could do to support serializing this / a way to get the same feature set but getting the result in chuncks maybe?

There's nothing special about my serialization code :

```
    public static byte[] Serialize(this object o)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(ms, o);
        ms.Position = 0;
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

The object i'm serializing contains arrays of items that themselves contains array etc, but the full graph itself isn't "that" large (it's the result of indexing data that, at the source, is already only around 1GB in size).

It's not due to GC fragmentation either (compacting the large heap didn't help).

Comment: I assume you are using a 64-bit OS?

Comment: Is there a reason you're serializing something that big in memory rather than file?  If I'm looking at this right, your memory requirements are at least 3 times the size of the structure (structure itself, MemoryStream contents of it, and byte array from MemoryStream) at a single point of execution.  Can you serialize to file instead?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov AnyCPU on a 64 bit OS (so should be 64 bit unless i missunderstood?)

Comment: @LB2 It's never getting stored, it's serialized, passed to another process, and deserialized there all at once, i'm using binary serialization for speed mostly

Comment: No it will be x86, unless you un-check "prefer 32-bit".

Comment: Where would i find the prefer 32 bit check?

Comment: Does your process show as "yourprocess.exe *32"? in Task Manager? If so, it is running in 32-bit mode.

Comment: Damn found it, when did that happen? Haven't seen that check before (and why would someone target any cpu with prefer 32 bit instead of targeting X86?!!)

Comment: That was it btw, now it's actually running as 64 bit and no longer posing this problem, this has to be the worse opt-out type of change i've ever seen lol. Can you rephrase that as an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: B/w, you're missing `using` around your `MemoryStream` which may be contributing to your memory woes (though not the core issue here).

Comment: @LB2 Good catch, no clue how i let it slide (what's ironic is i do have it in the deserialization code)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By default AnyCPU runs as 32 bit process on both x86 and x64 OS. So even with `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` set on x64 OS you run into 4GB limit of address space (2GB on x86).

To change uncheck "prefer 32 bit" property on solution properties -> "build" tab.

The details and history can be found in following answer: [What is the purpose of the "Prefer 32-bit" setting in Visual Studio 2012 and how does it actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066638/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-prefer-32-bit-setting-in-visual-studio-2012-and-how)