# C# pointer exceeds IntPtr limit

Tags: c#

I'm  trying to read a process's memory, but the address I would like to start reading from exceeds the IntPtr and UIntPtr limit.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "ReadProcessMemory")]
    private static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, [Out] int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

ReadProcessMemory(ProcessHandle, (IntPtr)0x14EC7B38A, buffer, buffer.Length, bytesused);
```

Doing this produces a OverflowException exception even if I use a `UIntPtr`. I have tried using a `ulong`, but this produces an AccessViolationException exception. What other data type should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows is a 64-bit OS. UInt is 64bits wide. I assume the problem is that your application is either built for 32bit or is built to "Prefer 32bit" (the Visual Studio defaults).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066638/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-prefer-32-bit-setting-in-visual-studio-2012-and-how) has the details of the setting you want to change.