# BadImageFormatException in System.Reactive.Core.dll

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

I'm puzzled about an exception that I get in a fairly simple project from Rx.

I googled the `BadImageFormatException` and found it's thrown when a platform-specific assembly is attempted to be loaded into an incompatible process.

The platform settings of my project are "Any CPU" though, and `System.Reactive.Core.dll` itself is too, obviously.

The stack trace's top is in Rx:

[image]

the sources for which read

```
    protected override void OnNextCore(T value)
    {
        _onNext(value);
    }
```

`_onNext` being an `Action<...>`.

My immediate problem is that I don't know how to figure which assembly actually fails to load - the information isn't in the exception I'm getting, and I don't know where else to get it from either.

I don't think it's actually anything about Rx, but what is it?

Anyone any ideas?

**EDIT 1:**

Here's the result of fuslogvw on a non-debugger run, set to "show all bindings", together with the stack trace I'm getting from the exception. Setting fuslogvw to show only failed bindings gives me nothing at all.

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

I also made sure "prefer 32 bit" is set to off in all assemblies that are from me, especially the main console app.

**EDIT 3:**

Absolutely baffling: I now broke the solution down, removed all dependencies including rx, and copy-pasted the sources to a new solution with all projects straight out of the wizard - it's still happening.

I tried it on two other machines, still happening.

What the hell is this!?

I my desperation, here're the sources. Perhaps someone smarter than me is curious enough:

[source code](https://github.com/jtheisen/moldinium.git)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to download Windows SDK and use fuslogvw tool to debug assembly bindings.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717422(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Added info about a fuslogvw run.

Answer (score 1):

Usually (and I don't mean always), the `BadImageFormatException` gets thrown when the assembly is either corrupt or the "bitness" (i.e. 32-bit, 64-bit) is different, in other words the executing assembly is compiled against a different "bitness" than the assembly being loaded.

In Visual Studio, even though you selected the `Any CPU` option, check to see if the `Prefer 32 bit` is set or not. It could be that there is still a mixture of 32-bit and 64-bit assemblies being compiled in your application.

See this for more info on the `Prefer 32 bit` field:
[What is the purpose of the "Prefer 32-bit" setting in Visual Studio 2012 and how does it actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066638/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-prefer-32-bit-setting-in-visual-studio-2012-and-how)

Another way to check your assemblies is to download and install a nice tool called [`Assembly Information`](https://assemblyinformation.codeplex.com/) which will tell you more about the .NET assembly.

Comment: These were indeed enabled, but unsetting it didn't change anything. Assembly Information is a cool took, but curiously it seems to be unable to open assemblies that were compiled with "prefer 32-bit". Still don't have a clue as to what's going on. I made sure I compiled everything from scratch.

Comment: Then the question becomes, what other platforms could it have targeted? Is it maybe compiled with a .NET that is not for Windows Desktop but for Mobile or something else perhaps?

Comment: And the Reactive Core DLL?

Comment: Referenced are the files in "net45", also Assembly Information gives me the same dependency on mscorlib (including PublicKeyToken) my own exe gives me.

Comment: Do you have colleagues that have the same problem as you with this exception?

Comment: It's a private project, never happened to me before or read about something similar.

Comment: Either that or .NET. Sorry, I have no futher advice to give.