# NullReferenceException when opening a subkey I know exists

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, registry, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to open a registry key so I can delete its subkeys:

```
Dim asu As New System.Security.Principal.NTAccount(username.Text)
Dim si As System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier = asu.Translate(GetType(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier))

Dim MyReg As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
MyReg = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, host.Text) _
    .OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\currentVersion\ProfileList\" & si.ToString & "\")

Dim myval As String
myval = MyReg.GetValue("Guid")
MsgBox(myval.ToString) ' retuns GUID no errors

Dim guid As String
guid = myval

Dim MyReg2 As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
MyReg2 = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, host.Text) _
    .OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileGuid\")

MsgBox(MyReg2.ToString)
'myreg2.DeleteSubKey(guid)
```

Now I have tested other keys on the same level:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileNotification`

They all return values, but when trying to open `ProfileGuid` it throws a `NullReferenceException`. I have full access to the remote registry and I've also tested it locally with the same results. I know the key exists.

Is they any way I can delete it directly without opening subkeys? Or can anyone explain why it is returning null?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: ive also tried looping through the top level HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\   

 `code ` Dim SubKeyNames() As String = MyReg2.GetSubKeyNames()
                    For Each s As String In SubKeyNames
                        MsgBox(s.ToString)
                    Next  `code `
i have also given "everyone" full access to the key  still returning nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely experiencing what's called [***Registry Redirection***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx).

To maintain compatibility with 32-bit applications, 64-bit versions of Windows implemented the [**File System Redirector**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx) and the **Registry Redirector**. The purpose of these two is to keep a seperate set of files and registry keys (usually goes under the name WOW64) that are specific to 32-bit applications only.

For instance, due to that a 64-bit process cannot load 32-bit code, a separate system directory is kept with only 32-bit versions of the system DLLs and applications. The path to the 32-bit system directory is `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64`, while the 64-bit directory is the standard `%SystemRoot%\System32`.

This works the same way in the registry, though only a certain set of keys have a respective 32-bit key. The 32-bit key is always located as a subkey of the standard 64-bit key (for example `HKLM\SOFTWARE`) and is called `Wow6432Node`.

The File System Redirector (and respectively the Registry Redirector) automatically *redirects* all 32-bit apps to the respective 32-bit directory/registry key to ensure that 32-bit apps still work on 64-bit systems. By default Visual Studio projects target 32-bit ***only***.

As far as I know there are two ways to overcome this problem:

1. **Compile your app as `AnyCPU` instead of `x86`.**

   This is by far the most simple solution. By doing this the app will automatically run as a 32-bit app on a 32-bit system, or as a 64-bit app on a 64-bit system. Thus the Registry Redirector won't need to intervene.
2. **Specify if you want to access the 32-bit view or the 64-bit view of the registry.**

   The .NET Framework has a built in feature that lets you specify if you want to access the 32-bit view or the 64-bit view of the registry. Combine that with [**`Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine which view you want to access.

   **Local solution (for others seeing this):**

   ```
   'Determine which registry view to use.
   Dim RegView As RegistryView = If(Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem, RegistryView.Registry64, RegistryView.Registry32)

   'Opens HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE with the specified registry view.
   Using RegHive As RegistryKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegView)

       'Open the "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileGuid" key.
       Using RegKey As RegistryKey = RegHive.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileGuid", True)
           'Do stuff with the registry key...
       End Using
   End Using
   ```

   **Remote solution:**

   (same as above, but changed the `Using RegHive As RegistryKey` line)

   ```
   Using RegHive As RegistryKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, host.txt, RegView)
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much - oddly i already add it set to compile to AnyCPU but the second method you posted worked well thank you.

Comment: @RobbieHoskins : Glad I could help! Happy coding!

Comment: @RobbieHoskins : The reason `AnyCPU` didn't automatically work could be because you've checked `Prefer 32-bit`. See this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12066638