# Deleting Subkeys in Subkey (Registry)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I wanna delete this registry key:

[image]

I tried a many codes but nothing worked, someone got an idea how to delete these? And I tried `DeleteSubKeyTree` too.. Nothing worked yet.

I tried this:

```
Try Dim x As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey x =
  Microsoft.Win32.Registry.localmachine.OpenSubKey("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\VB", True) 
  x.DeleteSubKeyTree("Test") 
catch ex as exception 
    messagebox.show ex.tostring() 
end try
```

But then I'm getting an error or exception that says:

> the subkey doesnt exist

I wanna delete "MyTestKey" on the picture and its subkeys..

Comment: Show what you tried...

Comment: I tried things like this:                                                                                             Try
Dim x As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
           x = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.localmachine.OpenSubKey("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\VB", True)
        x.DeleteSubKeyTree("Test")
catch ex as exception
   messagebox.show ex.tostring()
end try -- But nothing worked

Comment: Edit your question, add the code and format it properly. Code in comments isn't easy to read. When you tried the code you posted, what didn't work exactly? Help us to help you...

Comment: Ok, I edited my question

Comment: Your code says to delete the SubKeyTree called "Test" yet your screenshot and comments say it's called "TestKey". We can't even see your registry tree as the screenshot cuts it off.

Comment: I just wanna delete the Key "MyTestKey" and "Testkey" then subkey "Testkey" and "testkey1" you understand? Sry for my bad english.

Comment: And I didnt edited the code, the "test" must be "MyTestKey"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NullReferenceException when opening a subkey I know exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492135/nullreferenceexception-when-opening-a-subkey-i-know-exists) (see the answer)