# GetValueNames() of protected registry in vb.net

Tags: windows, vb.net, registry, windows-defender

I have the following folder in registry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Exclusions\Paths
```

But how can I show their value name to listbox?
Here is my code:

```
Dim FontKey As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Exclusions\Paths")
For Each ValueName As String In FontKey.GetValueNames()
    Dim Value As Object = FontKey.GetValue(ValueName) 'Get the value (data) of the specified value name.
    If Value IsNot Nothing Then 'Make sure it exists.
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Value.ToString())
    End If
Next
FontKey.Close()
```

P/s: I get this error: (Because I do not have the requisite permissions to create a new key)

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
>
> FontKey was Nothing.

Comment: There's a difference between a `NullReferenceException` and the `SecurityException` that is actually thrown when you _**don't**_ have access to a registry key. In this case the former occurs because the key you opened doesn't exist, which is likely caused by your application viewing the 32-bit version of the registry key (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\...` rather than `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\...`). Either compile your application as x64 or AnyCPU, or force it to view the 64-bit registry: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48603247/3740093

Comment: how can i solve it?

Comment: Read the very last sentence of my comment. The link to my earlier answer explains a little more what's going on, along with a second solution.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have converted it to x64, but I only show 0 in my ListBox, how can I display value name of all keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the value name then just ignore retrieving the value and add the `ValueName` variable to the list box instead:

```
For Each ValueName As String In FontKey.GetValueNames()
    ListBox1.Items.Add(ValueName)
Next
```

---

As for the error:

There's a difference between a `NullReferenceException` and the `SecurityException` that is *actually* thrown when you **don't** have access to a registry key. In this case the former occurs because the key you opened doesn't exist, which is likely caused by your application viewing the 32-bit version of the registry key (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\...`) rather than the 64-bit version (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\...`).

To fix this, either compile your application as x64 or AnyCPU, or force it to view the 64-bit registry. See my answer here for more information: [NullReferenceException when opening a subkey I know exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48603247/3740093)

Comment: Oh, thank you! Visual Vincent, If you want to activate windows / office, you can contact me: https://www.facebook.com/dphuc23

Comment: how can I write to folder:
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Exclusions\Paths"?

Comment: @DuyPhúc : [**`OpenSubKey(String, Boolean)`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.opensubkey?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#Microsoft_Win32_RegistryKey_OpenSubKey_System_String_System_Boolean_)

Comment: I use this (but it not work!)

        My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Exclusions\Paths", True).SetValue("Test", 0)

Comment: It show: 

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: @DuyPhúc : Remove `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ `, you've already opened it with `My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine`.

Comment: sorry about this convenient, but I have this problem:


I use:         My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Exclusions\Paths", True).SetValue("Test", 0)


. But it show: System.Security.SecurityException: 'Requested registry access is not allowed.'

Comment: @DuyPhúc : Now you see what really happens when you don't have access to a registry key :). Try running your application with administrative privileges: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2818776

Comment: If that doesn't work then I can't help you. You can try asking a new question, but it's not certain you'll get an answer.