# Understanding 32-bit vs 64-bit in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, 32bit-64bit

I've always skirted around the issue of building 64-bit desktop apps as I somehow got it in my head that it wasn't a trivial thing to do, plus I guess I didn't really understand the solution "configuration manager" dialog, platforms and configurations, either.

Anyway, I've just tried converting an existing application by simply changing all of the solution projects' platforms to x64, and it worked. The only issue I had was with a C++ DLL referenced by one of the projects, which needed rebuilding as x64.

So my question (finally) is: why did I only have an issue with the C++ DLL, but the many .Net assembly DLLs referenced by the projects in my solution were fine?

And what actually determines whether my application is built as 64-bit? I changed all of the solution's projects to "x64", but would it still have worked if they were left as "Any CPU", and I only changed the WPF (startup) project to "x64"?

**Edit**

So in the end it seems that I was simply able to set all project platforms to "Any CPU" rather than "x64" (the TFS server wasn't able to run unit tests with the latter). Even the projects referencing the unmanaged 64-bit DLL seem happy with this (not sure why).

The trick was to uncheck the `Prefer 32-bit` option in the WPF (startup) project's properties. The built application now runs as a 64-bit app, and TFS/unit tests run happily.

Comment: The IL code generated by the C# compiler doesn't care or even know (in general) whether it's going to be running as 32 bit or 64 bit. The JIT compiler takes care of that. So managed code can easily be run on either platform.

Comment: You can configure all class library projects that don't invoke unmanaged code (and doesn't contain references to architecture-specific libraries) to "Any CPU".

Comment: Well, all you had to do in your C++ project was to change the platform.  And all you have to do in your C# project is to change the platform.  But it is a different setting, not selected by the solution platform.  Right-click your EXE project > Properties > Build tab.  Be sure to change it for both the Debug and Release build.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I suggest removing the "prefer 32 bits" option, otherwise the program will run on 32bits on intel/amd processors (but on 64 bits on platforms without support for 32 bits) (technically more complex. It will run at 32 bits if there is a support for 32 bits, otherwise it will run at 64 bits. In the next few years some OS will drop 32 bits support)

Comment: @HansPassant is there a reason why each project's platform (in project properties) can be set independently of the values listed in the solution Configuration Manager? It took me a while to realise that setting the latter doesn't necessarily set the former, and caught me out a few times.

Comment: The platform selection is just not that well defined.  Particularly a sticking point for managed projects since it doesn't matter, the build tools are the same.  AnyCPU is a good name for a managed project platform, but not usable for C++ projects.  So you'll easily end up with a mix.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis please see my edit above. In the end I was able to set all projects to "Any CPU", even those referencing my unmanaged 64-bit DLL. I don't understand why though?

Comment: The compiler doesn't validate this against the target architecture of unmanaged dll's, and as MatthewWatson mentioned, the result IL is the same regardless. You have to manually specify the target platform to inform the users of your library that (part of) it only runs (correctly) in that platform.

Comment: Prefer 32-bit was meant for ARM32, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066638/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-prefer-32-bit-setting-in-visual-studio-2012-and-how

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a correctness standpoint 32/64 only matters when you are interoperating with native code, using low-level unsafe features, or allocating a lot (> 4GB) of memory. Absent those considerations you might as well just use AnyCpu. AnyCpu code will default to your host OS bitness (though that default can be altered), so for most people these days it will end up running in a 64 bit process.

There are sometimes performance reasons to explicitly prefer 32 or 64 bits. 32 bit apps will generally be more cache friendly. Compute-bound apps should perform better when run as 64 bit processes (though not always).

Comment: Doesn't it also mean 64bit runs by a 64bit version of CLR? And JITcompiles it to 64bit assembly/instruction set?

Comment: @Konrad Yes, that is correct, but in general there shouldn't be (m)any differences you need to care about.

Comment: One other case: calling 32-bit in-process COM components. Where I work everyone still has 32-bit MS Office installed, so to launch an email in Outlook I had to force my build to be 32-bit.

Comment: Cache friendly. Can you please explain this part. I think 64 will have more cache runtime cache and thus will perform way better than 32bit

Comment: In 32 bit code, pointers are only 32 bits, so if your data structures are "pointer rich" then they will need less memory in 32 bits. So for a give cache size, more data will fit in a 32 bit app then a 64 bit app.

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR**: .Net  assemblies are never assembled in to machine specific instructions, instead they are compiled into MSIL which runs under the .Net virtual machine, at runtime the VM uses the JITer to produce machine instructions which can be executed by the CPU.

---

The differences between `32bit` and `64bit` that "breaks" object file are either: *Pointer size*, *Memory model* and most importantly the **instruction set architecture (ISA)**. Lets break down each point and see why `.Net` assemblies are mostly unaffected.

## Point Size (or Length)

In a `32bit` execution environment pointers are 32 bit long, and as you'd expect int 64 bit they are 64 bit long. This fact can break your assembly in one of two ways:

1. Structures containing pointers will have their internal memory structure changes are they need more (or less) bytes to store pointers.
2. Pointer arithmetic - some clever developers like to play around with pointers, masking them, adding them and so on. In some cases the size of the pointer may be integral for these computations to yield correct results.

#### Why .Net assemblies are not affected

Since .Net languages are `safe` - you don't get to play with pointers (generally, unless you are under an unsafe context). Not having the option to play with pointers solves the 2nd point. As for the first point - this is the reason you can get the size (using `sizeof`) of a class no the size of a struct containing class references.

## Memory Model

The old `32bit` processors used to have a feature called `Memory segmentation` which allowed the `OS` or a `Supervisor program` to declare regions of memory that are accessed using special `CPU registers` called `Segment registers`. In `64bit` this feature is mostly disabled. So programs compile to work under memory segmentation may have problems working in a non segmented environment.

#### Why .Net assemblies are not affected

Generally we don't deal with memory at this low level, this is possible because of the `.Net virtual machine` as explained in the next point.

## Instruction Set Architecture

`32bit` and `64bit` (`x86` and `AMD64`) are similar but completely different `ISAs` which means that code which was assembled to run under one will not run under the other. So unlike the other two points this one will break your assembly regardless of what you've written in it.

#### Why .Net assemblies are not affected

So how could .Net assemblies possibly be compiled as `Any CPU`? The trick is that when you compile a .Net language you never assemble it. That means when you press `compile` you only compile your code into an intermediate object (known as a .Net assembly) that is not assembled (ie. not ran through an assembler).

Usually when you compile code in `C/++` you first run it through a compile the generates some `assembly instructions` these instructions are then passed down to an `assembler` which generates `machine instructions`. The CPU is only capable of executing these `machine instructions`.

.Net languages are different, as mentioned above, when you compile a .Net language you run it through a compiler and stop there, no assembler involved. The compile here, too, generates some `assembler instructions` but unlike the instructions produced by a `c/c++` compile these instructions are machine agnostic, they are written in language called `MSIL - Microsoft intermediate language`. No CPU knowns how to execute these instructions, since just like ordinary assembler instructions they too must be assembled into machine instructions.

The trick is that this all happens at run time, when a user opens you program he launches an instance of the `.Net runtime` in which your program runs, your program never runs directly against the native machine itself. When your program needs to call a method a special component in the .Net virtual machine called the `JITer - just in time compiler` is tasked with assembling this method from MSIL to machine instructions specific for the machine the .Net framework was installed on.

Comment: I notice that in 32-bit, when you catch an exception and you are in a breakpoint inside a catch block, you can drag the cursor (Set Next Statement) out of the catch block. Whereas in 64-bit, there will be an error in Visual Studio (3 possible errors, one of which is related to stack unwinding). Can anybody shed light on this behavior?

Comment: The low-level exception handling details on x86 differ quite a bit from x64 (and from arm and arm64 -- x86 is the oddball case). 

On x86 the emitted code for a catch is in the same chunk of codegen as the rest of the method and they share a common stack frame. On the other architectures catch code is split out into funclets and these funclets have separate code and stack from the main method And that separation makes it difficult for the debugger to repoint control on x64 like it can on x86.