# How to get a 64bit exe file from the solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When you make any project using Visual Studio there's usually the "Release" and the "Debug" folder, which contain the .exe files of the solutions. How do I "export" a 64bit version of that exe?

Comment: add a new one and set it to x64

Comment: Set the CPU architecture to x64.

Comment: The bitness does not matter, .NET programs can run on any processor.  AnyCPU is a very apt name.  You can force a particular jitter being used, you do that with Project > Properties > Build tab.  the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox is turned on in the standard project templates, historically the Visual Studio tooling worked better in 32-bit mode.  Those days are about gone, the added support for 64-bit Edit+Continue and the x64 jitter rewrite makes it pretty unnecessary.  Simply untick the option and you'll get a 64-bit process on a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: Could be considered a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066638/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-prefer-32-bit-setting-in-visual-studio-2012-and-how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you right click your project, then choose properties, under the Build option, there is an option called Platform target with a drop down, you can switch this to target Any CPU, x64, and x86. Just set this to x64 if you want it to target 64 bit only, but then you run the risk of your application not working on a 32 bit system.

Answer (score 2):

1. Right-click your project and select `Properties`:
   [image: Right click your project]
2. On your `Build` tab, select `Platform target` to `x64`:
   [image: Select x64]
3. Don't forget that you should also change `Configuration` to `Release` and select `x64` again so that Debug and Release configurations are all x64.
   [image: Select x64 on Release]

---

Note:

1. If your project needs a XAML designer, the designer will stop working if your project targets x64.
2. You can select AnyCPU and uncheck "Prefer 32~bit" instead of x64 because it will also run as a 64-bit process in a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: It's better to uncheck "Prefer 32-bit" as Hans Passant has commented, that way you don't lose anything but will instead default to 64-bit process on a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: Thanks @LasseVågsætherKarlsen , I added your suggestion "uncheck Prefer 32-bit" into my answer. And I just forgot that.