# Out of memory error when creating large lists in memory vb.net

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, memory

I need to work with a large amount of data in memory. I am loading it from an SQLite database on SSD and using EF6 to construct business objects from it. As soon as the Process Memory window shows usage hitting 3.2GB I get an Out Of Memory exception from Entity Framework.

For now I am just loading into lists. I had read somewhere that there were limits on the sizes of list structures so instead of using one big list I have created multiple simple DataBlock container objects to each hold a chunk of the required data. It doesnt seem to make any difference. The PC has plenty of RAM (16GB). I am using a new context to populate each DataBlock and then destroying them.

```
For Each DataBlock In DataBlocks
    Using Context As New mainEntities
        Dim FirstRecordTimeUTC As Long = TimeFunctions.ConvertDateToUTC(DataBlock.StartDate)
        Dim LastRecordTimeUTC As Long = TimeFunctions.ConvertDateToUTC(DataBlock.EndDate)

        Dim CandlesInRange = (From Cand In Context.HistoricalRecords
                              Where Cand.time_close_utc >= FirstRecordTimeUTC
                              Where Cand.time_close_utc <= LastRecordTimeUTC
                              Order By Cand.id
                              Select Cand).ToList
        DataBlock.AllCandles = CandlesInRange

        Dim RTsInRange = (From Cand In Context.HistoricalRecordRealTimes
                          Where Cand.time_close_utc >= FirstRecordTimeUTC
                          Where Cand.time_close_utc <= LastRecordTimeUTC
                          Order By Cand.id
                          Select Cand).ToList
        DataBlock.AllRTs = RTsInRange

        Dim StatsInRange = (From Cand In Context.InstrumentStats
                            Where Cand.time_close_utc >= FirstRecordTimeUTC
                            Where Cand.time_close_utc <= LastRecordTimeUTC
                            Order By Cand.id
                            Select Cand).ToList
        DataBlock.AllStats = StatsInRange
    End Using 
Next
```

The compiler platform is set to 'Any CPU'. System is as follows:

**Win 10 64, VS 2017, 16GB RAM, Ryzen 5 3600**

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's not about system memory specifically but process memory.  Look into allocating more memory to your process.

Comment: Projects targeting AnyCPU and .NET 4.5 and higher by default use the configuration "AnyCPU 32-bit preferred". This means that your application will always be compiled as a 32-bit app (which are by default limited to 4 GB of RAM) even on a 64-bit system, the exception being when you're running on an ARM processor (in which case it will be compiled to ARM).

Comment: You need to target the classic AnyCPU configuration in order for your app to compile as a 64-bit app on your 64-bit system. Right-click your project in the Solution Explorer and press `Properties`, go to the `Compile` tab and uncheck the box labeled `Prefer 32-bit` (it might be under `Advanced Compile Options` as well... I don't have VS in front of me at the moment).

Comment: Depends largely on what you do with these lists. The preferred approach is to try and convert this process to a streaming solution.

Comment: Thank you so much Visual Vincent that did the trick! If you made it into an answer I would mark it as the solution. You're a legend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the "Prefer 32-bit" setting in Visual Studio and how does it actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066638/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-prefer-32-bit-setting-in-visual-studio-and-how-does)

Comment: Glad I could help. I think the duplicate I suggested is better suited as an "answer" as it explains a bit more thorougly what `Prefer 32-bit` is and how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Vincent has answered this question best in the comments:

> Projects targeting AnyCPU and .NET 4.5 and higher by default use the
>   configuration "AnyCPU 32-bit preferred". This means that your
>   application will always be compiled as a 32-bit app (which are by
>   default limited to 4 GB of RAM) even on a 64-bit system, the exception
>   being when you're running on an ARM processor (in which case it will
>   be compiled to ARM).
>
> You need to target the classic AnyCPU configuration in order for your
>   app to compile as a 64-bit app on your 64-bit system. Right-click your
>   project in the Solution Explorer and press Properties, go to the
>   Compile tab and uncheck the box labeled Prefer 32-bit (it might be
>   under Advanced Compile Options as well... I don't have VS in front of
>   me at the moment).

He also referenced another question that explains this setting:
[What is the purpose of the “Prefer 32-bit” setting in Visual Studio and how does it actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066638/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-prefer-32-bit-setting-in-visual-studio-and-how-does)