# How to disable 'prefer 32-bit' on VS2022?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2022

Microsoft made the `Any CPU` option dependent on a property of `prefer 32-bit` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12066638/939213) for example). Previously we could disable that on the options of the project.

Now, however, I can't find it in the project's properties.

Where is it hiding?

(To replicate: Create a new WPF project and disable the `prefer 32-bit` option. How to disable it, you ask? So do I.)

Comment: What .NET version are you targeting? Is the OS 32- or 64-bit? Do you want to run your app as 32- or 64-bit?

Comment: @mm8 .NET 6.0. OS is 64-bit. I want to run it as 64 on 64, and as 32 on 32.

Comment: Then you should simply set the platform target to `Any CPU` and keep the default values.

Comment: you really shouldn't worry too much unless you have native dependencies

Comment: LOL, 'new property' is more than a decade old, and has actually been disabled for new projects.

Comment: I mean, it is false now. The reason, they made that weird thing, was that the first 64-bit CPUs actually were optimized to 32-bit. However this is no longer true, which is why they have removed that option. You can easily check your process in task manager, if it is 32-bit, it will have `(32-bit)` after the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run your .NET 6 app as a 64-bit processes on a 64-bit operating system and as a 32-bit process on a 32-bit machine, the only thing you need to do is to set the target platform to `Any CPU`.

When running the app you should then be able to confirm that the `Environment.Is64BitProcess` property returns `true` on a 64-bit system.