# Why am I getting: "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown"

Tags: c#, xml

I'm writing the osm(xml) file in C#.

With the `List<T>` I am writing the child element (osmelement) by using a `foreach` loop. At that time, I am getting the error:

> System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

In the small wpf project, if I set the target platform to 64x bit, it is working fine, but I need it in my main project where it will work only in AnyCPU or x86. But if set to AnyCPU, I get this error.

Please refer the code.

Is there any other way I can add the child elements at a time with the list in osm(xml) file?

```
XmlElement osmElement = doc.CreateElement("osm");
osmElement.SetAttribute("version", "0.6");`

foreach (var item in osmNodes)
{
    // getting error here 
    osmElement.AppendChild(item.ToXmlElement(doc));  
}

public XmlElement ToXmlElement(XmlDocument doc)
{
    //string _datetimestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
    XmlElement nodeElement = doc.CreateElement("node");
    nodeElement.SetAttribute("id", Id.ToString());
    nodeElement.SetAttribute("lat", Lat.ToString());
    nodeElement.SetAttribute("lon", Lon.ToString());

    return nodeElement;
}
```

Expected Output in file

```
    <osm version='0.6' upload='false'>
      <node id='-101752' lat='18.4508611' lon='77.3322991' />
      <node id='-101753' lat='18.4508432' lon='77.3326495' />
      <node id='-101754' lat='18.4508658' lon='77.332924' />
    <osm/>
```

Where `osmNodes` is defined as `List<T>`.

Comment: XmlReader is used to read huge xml files and used it often with 1GB xml.   So try XmlWriter instead of XmlDocument.

Comment: Make sure you don't have "Prefer 32-bit" checked, see [What is the purpose of the "Prefer 32-bit" setting in Visual Studio and how does it actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12066638).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are building your entire `XmlDocument` [XML DOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/reading-an-xml-document-into-the-dom) in memory, then (presumably) writing it out somewhere.  The XML DOM is very memory-intensive since all values are represented as strings, which is likely causing the problem you are seeing.

Instead, you should stream your [OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page) content directly to file, or to some response stream, or wherever you will ultimately write its contents, without creating an intermediate XML DOM.

You don't show your C# classes, so let's assume you have an `OsmElement` type that looks like this:

```
public class OsmElement
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Lon { get; set; }
}
```

And you have some `List<OsmElement> osmNodes` that you want to **stream** to an [OSM XML file](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML).  You have two ways you could do this.

**Firstly**, you could write it directly with [`XmlWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter).  This class

> Represents a writer that provides a fast, non-cached, forward-only way to generate streams or files that contain XML data.

And so has fixed memory overhead.  First, define the following static methods:

```
public static class OsmExtensions
{
    public static void SerializeToFile(string fileName, Dictionary<string, string> rootAttributes, List<OsmElement> osmNodes, XmlWriterSettings settings = default)
    {
        using var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
        SerializeToStream(stream, rootAttributes, osmNodes, settings);
    }
    
    public static void SerializeToStream(Stream stream, Dictionary<string, string> rootAttributes, List<OsmElement> osmNodes, XmlWriterSettings settings = default)
    {
        using var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings);
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("osm");
        // Hardcode the version
        writer.WriteAttributeString("version", "0.6");
        // Write other attributes as required
        foreach (var attr in rootAttributes)
            writer.WriteAttributeString(attr.Key, attr.Value);
        foreach (var item in osmNodes)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("node");
            writer.WriteStartAttribute("id");
            writer.WriteValue(item.Id); 
            writer.WriteStartAttribute("lat");
            writer.WriteValue(item.Lat);  // Do not use item.Lat.ToString() as the value returned will be localized.
            writer.WriteStartAttribute("lon");
            writer.WriteValue(item.Lon);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
    }
}
```

And now you will be able to write a `List<OsmElement> osmNodes` to a file as follows:

```
var fileName = "Question77035356.osm";
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = true, // Set to false if you don't want indenting
};
Dictionary<string, string> attributes = new()
{
    { "upload", "false" },
};
OsmExtensions.SerializeToFile(fileName, attributes, osmNodes, settings);
```

Notes:

- If you are writing to some response stream or other `Stream` instead of to a file, use `OsmExtensions.SerializeToStream()`.
- When formatting numeric values to XML, do not use `double.ToString()` or `float.ToString()` as the return will be **localized** -- e.g. a comma will be used as a decimal separator in certain locales.  Instead use [`XmlWriter.WriteValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.writevalue) or [`XmlConvert.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert.tostring) to correctly format numeric values to XML.
- Rgeardless of whether you are running in 64-bit or 32-bit, streaming directly rather than building an XML DOM will be more performant.  However, if your `List<OsmElement>` is large enough, you might run out of memory when running in 32-bit mode simply by constructing the list.  If this happens, look to see whether you checked "Prefer 32-bit", and if so, **uncheck it**.  You will still be building your project in `AnyCPU` mode but it will run in 64-bit when possible.  For details, see *[What is the purpose of the "Prefer 32-bit" setting in Visual Studio and how does it actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12066638)*.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bTlQyi).

**Secondly**, you could define a model corresponding to your OSM XML file, and serialize it to your file or stream using [`XmlSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer).  The serializer uses `XmlWriter` to write and so also streams its output.

First, modify your data model as follows by adding a root type and annotating your classes with [attributes that control `XmlSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/attributes-that-control-xml-serialization):

```
[XmlRoot("osm", Namespace = "")]
public class OsmModel
{
    [XmlAttribute("version")]
    public string Version { get; set; } = "0.6";
    
    [XmlAttribute("upload")]
    public string Upload { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("generator")]
    public string Generator { get; set; }
    
    [XmlElement("node")]
    public List<OsmElement> OsmNodes { get; set; }
}

public class OsmElement
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("lat")]
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("lon")]
    public double Lon { get; set; }
}
```

Now rewrite your serialization code as follows:

```
public static class OsmExtensions
{
    public static void SerializeToFile(string fileName, OsmModel model, XmlWriterSettings settings = default)
    {
        using var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
        SerializeToStream(stream, model, settings);
    }
    
    public static void SerializeToStream(Stream stream, OsmModel model, XmlWriterSettings settings = default)
    {
        using var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(model.GetType());
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", ""); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd lines.
        serializer.Serialize(writer, model, ns);
    }
}
```

And you will be able to serialize your `List<OsmElement> osmNodes` like so:

```
var model = new OsmModel
{
    Upload = "false",
    OsmNodes = osmNodes,
};
var fileName = "Question77035356.osm";
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = true, // Set to false if you don't want indenting
};
OsmExtensions.SerializeToFile(fileName, model, settings);
```

With both approaches the XML generated looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" upload="false">
  <node id="-101752" lat="18.4508611" lon="77.3322991" />
  <node id="-101753" lat="18.4508432" lon="77.3326495" />
  <node id="-101754" lat="18.4508658" lon="77.332924" />
</osm>
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TDjscU).

Comment: Thank you so much......it is helped me a lot. Thanks a lot once again.......!

Comment: @VinayakPattar - You're welcome.  If the question is answered, please do [mark it as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147532).

Answer (score -1):

If you need to use AnyCpu or x86 compile mode for your library to work, it's most likely that main app is x86 (aka 32bit) built and so lower memory limits apply. So the easy guess is simply that your list is to large. If you're saving the data to file, maybe consider some streaming XML int file instead of keeping the whole data in memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply...please will you help me with some sample am new to this concept.

Comment: Basically 32bit apps have theoretically max 2^32 = 4GB memory limit, but operating systems may actually limit this even more (this was the case with windows 2003). So basically all moder apps should user 64bit architecture, which is now native, so 64bit == any cpu. 64bit can address, again theoretically,  2^64 bit memory,.

Comment: As for sample, take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/perform-streaming-transform-large-xml-documents